# I have 2 wifi cards. Can I specify which interface to use when I run a script at the terminal?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip, network-interface

I have 2 wifi cards both connected to different routers in my residence. Is it possible to use a specific interface to run a script or program?

For example, if I run `curl icanhazip.com` can I specify the interface to use?

Answer (score 2):

With "ifconfig  up|down" you can activate or deactivate the interface. 
Also, with the "route" command, you can specify which ip-addresses are to be reached/routed thru what interface.